# Caching website data in Node.js

Tags: node.js, web-applications, express

I am completely new to Node.js and trying to figure out a few things. Originally I was using apache and in the .htaccess I used `mod_expires.c` to cache data. For instance I would do:

```
ExpiresByType text/css               "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
```

I also set up `mod_rewrite.c` for [cachebusting](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/wiki/cachebusting), so whenever I needed to update my css or javascript I could simply change the version in the html and the request would be routed to the regular file.

How can I implement these features in Node.js. I am currently using the [Express](http://expressjs.com/) module as well.

Answer (score 0):

`express.static` (which is just an exposed version of `connect.static` so the documentation can be found under connect) with a `maxAge` parameter should do most or all of what you want. Also look into `express.staticCache` (again, alias for `connect.staticCache`).